# How do I make a dependent dropdown select menu choice show/hide another dropdown select menu using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Sorry about the confusing title, but basically **my question is how do I use the selection from one dropdown menu to decide which dropdown menu shows up next?** I want to do something like this:
Select menu
option #1
option #2
option #3
Selecting option #1 would open another select menu:
sub-option #1.1
sub-option #1.2
sub-option #1.3
and the same thing for options #2 and #3, and THEN sub-option #1.1 would open another select menu.
I think I have the HTML down just fine, but I'm extremely rusty with Javascript.
https://jsfiddle.net/mun52n13/
Any ideas?
In my code, screen replacement should trigger #devices which, when selecting iphone should trigger #iphones, selecting ipad should trigger #ipads, and etc.
**HTML**

```
        <select name="service" id="service" class="service">
            <option>Select a Service</option>   
            <option value="screen" id="screen">Screen Replacement</option>     
            <option value="comp" id="comp">Computer Work</option> 
            <option value="misc" id="misc">Miscellaneous</option>
        </select>
        <div id="devices">
        <select name="devices" id="devices" class="devices">
            <option value="iphone" id="iphone">iPhone</option>     
            <option value="ipad" id="ipad">iPad</option>
            <option value="android" id="android">Android</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div id="iphones">
        <select name="iphone" id="iphone" class="iphone">
            <!--<option value="iphone6s" id="iphone6s">iPhone 6S</option> -->
            <!--<option value="iphone6splus" id="iphone6splus">iPhone 6S Plus</option>-->
            <option value="iphone6" id="iphone6">iPhone 6</option>
            <option value="iphone6plus" id="iphone6plus">iPhone 6 Plus</option>
            <option value="iphone5s" id="iphone5s">iPhone 5S</option>
            <option value="iphone5c" id="iphone5c">iPhone 5C</option>
            <option value="iphone5" id="iphone5">iPhone 5</option>
            <option value="iphone4s" id="iphone4s">iPhone 4S</option>
            <option value="iphone4" id="iphone4">iPhone 4</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div id="ipads">
        <select name="ipad" id="ipad" class="ipad">
            <option value="ipadmini3" id="ipadmini3">iPad Mini 3</option>
            <option value="ipadmini2" id="ipadmini2">iPad Mini 2</option>
            <option value="ipadair" id="ipadair">iPad Air</option>
            <option value="ipad4" id="ipad4">iPad 4</option>
            <option value="ipad3" id="ipad3">iPad 3</option>
            <option value="ipadmini" id="ipadmini">iPad Mini</option>
            <option value="ipad2" id="ipad2">iPad 2</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div id="computerwork">
        <select name="compwork" id="compwork" class="compwork">
            <option value="desktopcreation" id="desktopcreation">Desktop Creation</option>
            <option value="desktopbuild" id="desktopbuild">Desktop Build</option>
            <option value="hardwareupgrades" id="hardwareupgrades">Hardware Upgrades</option>
            <option value="datarecovery" id="datarecovery">Data Recovery/Transfer</option>
            <option value="spywareremoval" id="spywareremoval">Spyware/Adware Removal</option>
            <option value="virusremoval" id="virusremoval">Virus Removal</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div id="miscservices">
        <select name="miscellaneous" id="miscellaneous" class="miscellaneous">   
            <option value="networksecurity" id="networksecurity">Network Security</option> 
            <!--<option value="webdesign" id="webdesign">Website Design</option>-->
        </select>
        </div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#service').on('change', function() {
        $('#devices').hide();
        $('#iphones').hide();
        $('#ipads').hide();
        $('#computerwork').hide();
        $('#miscservices').hide();
      if ( this.value == 'screen')
      {
        $("#devices").show();
      }
      if ( this.value == 'iphone')
      {
        $("#iphones").show();
      }
      if ( this.value == 'ipad')
      {
        $("#ipads").show();
      }
      if ( this.value == 'comp')
      {
        $("#computerwork").show();
      }
      if ( this.value == 'misc')
      {
        $("#miscservices").show();
      }
      if ( this.value == 'comp')
      {
        $("#computerwork").show();
      }
      if ( this.value == 'miscservices')
      {
        $("#miscservices").show();
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a short prototype on how to make your thing work :
check the js fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/yehiaawad/mun52n13/6/

When you select devices from services select

=> services-devices would display

=> when selecting Iphone from devices select

=>devices-iphones should be displayed and the rest would be hidden

(the same thing with IPad)

HTML:

```
<select name="service" id="service" class="service">
            <option>Select a Service</option>   
            <option value="screen" data-target="devices" id="screen">Screen Replacement</option>       
            <option value="comp" data-target="comp" id="comp">Computer Work</option> 
            <option value="misc" data-target="misc" id="misc">Miscellaneous</option>
</select>
<div style="display:none" id="service-devices">
        <select name="devices" id="devices" class="devices">
        <option>Select a device</option>       
        <option value="iphone" data-target="iphones" id="iphone">iPhone</option>       
        <option value="ipad"  data-target="ipads" id="ipad">iPad</option>
        <option value="android" id="android">Android</option>
        </select>
<div style="display:none" id="devices-iphones">
        <select name="iphone" id="iphone" class="iphone">
        <!--<option value="iphone6s" id="iphone6s">iPhone 6S</option> -->
        <!--<option value="iphone6splus" id="iphone6splus">iPhone 6S Plus</option>-->
        <option></option>
        <option value="iphone6" id="iphone6">iPhone 6</option>
        <option value="iphone6plus" id="iphone6plus">iPhone 6 Plus</option>
        <option value="iphone5s" id="iphone5s">iPhone 5S</option>
        <option value="iphone5c" id="iphone5c">iPhone 5C</option>
        <option value="iphone5" id="iphone5">iPhone 5</option>
        <option value="iphone4s" id="iphone4s">iPhone 4S</option>
        <option value="iphone4" id="iphone4">iPhone 4</option>
        </select>
</div>
<div style="display:none" id="devices-ipads">
        <select name="ipad" id="ipad" class="ipad">
              <option></option>
        <option value="ipadmini3" id="ipadmini3">iPad Mini 3</option>
        <option value="ipadmini2" id="ipadmini2">iPad Mini 2</option>
        <option value="ipadair" id="ipadair">iPad Air</option>
        <option value="ipad4" id="ipad4">iPad 4</option>
        <option value="ipad3" id="ipad3">iPad 3</option>
        <option value="ipadmini" id="ipadmini">iPad Mini</option>
        <option value="ipad2" id="ipad2">iPad 2</option>
        </select>
</div>
</div>
<div style="display:none" id="service-comp">
        <select name="compwork" id="compwork" class="compwork">
        <option value="desktopcreation" id="desktopcreation">Desktop Creation</option>
        <option value="desktopbuild" id="desktopbuild">Desktop Build</option>
        <option value="hardwareupgrades" id="hardwareupgrades">Hardware Upgrades</option>
        <option value="datarecovery" id="datarecovery">Data Recovery/Transfer</option>
        <option value="spywareremoval" id="spywareremoval">Spyware/Adware Removal</option>
        <option value="virusremoval" id="virusremoval">Virus Removal</option>
        </select>
</div>
<div style="display:none" id="service-misc">
        <select name="miscellaneous" id="miscellaneous" class="miscellaneous">   
        <option value="networksecurity" id="networksecurity">Network Security</option> 
        <!--<option value="webdesign" id="webdesign">Website Design</option>-->
        </select>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').on('change', function() {
       var target=$(this).find(":selected").attr("data-target");
       var id=$(this).attr("id");
       $("div[id^='"+id+"']").hide();
       $("#"+id+"-"+target).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: That's perfect!! Later tonight when I have time to implement it I'll test it to make sure and mark your answer as correct. Thank you so much, that's a very neat method

Comment: Welcome if you have any questions do not hesitate

Comment: Worked just as it should! Now to figure out how to get the php part of the contact form to work with this haha.

Answer (score -1):

This is a way to do it: https://jsfiddle.net/mun52n13/7/

I created a `menu` class, a attribute `data-parent` to set the parent menu, and a attribute `data-target` to set the value associated with this menu.

So you can look for which menu should be shown or hidden.

CSS:

```
.menu {
  display: block;
}

.menu.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<select name="service" id="service" class="service menu">
  <option>Select a Service</option>
  <option value="screen" id="screen">Screen Replacement</option>
  <option value="comp" id="comp">Computer Work</option>
  <option value="misc" id="misc">Miscellaneous</option>
</select>
<select name="devices" id="devices" class="devices menu hidden" data-parent="#service" data-target="screen">
  <option></option>
  <option value="iphone" id="iphone">iPhone</option>
  <option value="ipad" id="ipad">iPad</option>
  <option value="android" id="android">Android</option>
</select>
<select name="iphone" id="iphone" class="iphone menu hidden" data-parent="#devices" data-target="iphone">
  <option></option>
  <!--<option value="iphone6s" id="iphone6s">iPhone 6S</option> -->
  <!--<option value="iphone6splus" id="iphone6splus">iPhone 6S Plus</option>-->
  <option value="iphone6" id="iphone6">iPhone 6</option>
  <option value="iphone6plus" id="iphone6plus">iPhone 6 Plus</option>
  <option value="iphone5s" id="iphone5s">iPhone 5S</option>
  <option value="iphone5c" id="iphone5c">iPhone 5C</option>
  <option value="iphone5" id="iphone5">iPhone 5</option>
  <option value="iphone4s" id="iphone4s">iPhone 4S</option>
  <option value="iphone4" id="iphone4">iPhone 4</option>
</select>
<select name="ipad" id="ipad" class="ipad menu hidden" data-parent="#devices" data-target="ipad">
  <option></option>
  <option value="ipadmini3" id="ipadmini3">iPad Mini 3</option>
  <option value="ipadmini2" id="ipadmini2">iPad Mini 2</option>
  <option value="ipadair" id="ipadair">iPad Air</option>
  <option value="ipad4" id="ipad4">iPad 4</option>
  <option value="ipad3" id="ipad3">iPad 3</option>
  <option value="ipadmini" id="ipadmini">iPad Mini</option>
  <option value="ipad2" id="ipad2">iPad 2</option>
</select>
<select name="compwork" id="compwork" class="compwork menu hidden" data-parent="#service" data-target="comp">
  <option></option>
  <option value="desktopcreation" id="desktopcreation">Desktop Creation</option>
  <option value="desktopbuild" id="desktopbuild">Desktop Build</option>
  <option value="hardwareupgrades" id="hardwareupgrades">Hardware Upgrades</option>
  <option value="datarecovery" id="datarecovery">Data Recovery/Transfer</option>
  <option value="spywareremoval" id="spywareremoval">Spyware/Adware Removal</option>
  <option value="virusremoval" id="virusremoval">Virus Removal</option>
</select>
<select name="miscellaneous" id="miscellaneous" class="miscellaneous menu hidden" data-parent="#service" data-target="misc">
  <option></option>
  <option value="networksecurity" id="networksecurity">Network Security</option>
  <!--<option value="webdesign" id="webdesign">Website Design</option>-->
</select>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu').change(function() {
    var id = this.id;
    var value = this.value;
    if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
      $('.menu[data-parent="#' + id + '"]').css('display', 'none').change();
    } else {
      $('.menu[data-parent="#' + id + '"]:not([data-target="' + value + '"])').css('display', 'none').change();
      $('.menu[data-parent="#' + id + '"][data-target="' + value + '"]').css('display', 'block').change();
    }
  });
});
```